# Error trying to load django admin images with NGINX

Tags: django, nginx

I am using NGINX, uwsgi (to serve my django files) and apache in my webserver.

But when I try to access the django admin page the images arent loading. The **NGINX** log says error 404 ("GET /static/admin/css/base.css/ HTTP/1.1" 404)

Here is my NGINX configuration:

```
    server {
    listen   80;
    server_name www.xyz.com xyz.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/xyz.com-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/xyz.com-error.log;

    location / {
        include        uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass     127.0.0.1:9001;
    }

    location /media {
        root   /srv/www/xyz.com.com.br/application/x;
    }
    location /templates {
        root   /srv/www/xyz.com.com.br/application/x;
    }       
    
        
}
```

The media directory (that contains css, js and imgs) are located in **/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/contrib/admin/media/**

I tried to give a location to it but I didnt have success...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I was missing "ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/srv/www/xyz.com.br/application/X/'
" in settings.py

Also I copied 
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/contrib/admin/media/
to 
/srv/www/xyz.com.br/application/x/static

and did this change in nginx:

```
    location /static {
         root /srv/www/xyz.com.br/application/x;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly because of the “/” suffix? Does it work if you request `http://example.com/static/admin/css/base.css` (*without* the trailing slash)?

Additionally, you don't seem to have the `/static` URL setup in your nginx config:

```
location /static {
    root /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3-py2.6.egg/django/contrib/admin/media/
}
```